# React and hmr, why Webpack ignores changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-hmr

I'm trying to build my React project with Webpack using hot module replacement. But, Webpack ignores file changes. What am I doing wrong?
My config:

```
  var path = require('path');
  var webpack = require('webpack');

  module.exports = {
    entry: [
      'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4567',
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      './src/index'
    ],
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      publicPath: '/static/'
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
      loaders: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
        include: [path.join(__dirname, 'src')]
      }]
    }
  };
```

My files structure:

```
src
--app
----actions
----components
----constants
----reducers
----app.js
----config.js
--index.js
```

Hot module replacement works fine if module file is in "src" folder, otherwise nothing happens on changes.

Thanks!

Comment: `module.loaders.include` is not "include path", it is condition as well as `module.loaders.test`. So, js loader will not applied to files located not in `src` folder.

Comment: remove include option does not work (`exclude: /node_modules/` instead)

Comment: While js-file in `src` folder HMR is works with `import Whatever from './whatever.js'` and not works with `src/app/components` and `import Whatever from './app/components/whatever.js'` ?

Comment: yes, `import App from './app'` works fine, but `import App from './app/app'` not

Comment: _nothing happens on changes_ means no messages in webpack-dev-server and browser consoles ?

Comment: yes, no messages.
Absolutely have no idea what it was, but I added '.js' to all file imports and now hmr works. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Because you've set `include` in your webpack config.

You can change your config like this:
var path = require('path');

```
  var webpack = require('webpack');

  module.exports = {
    entry: [
      'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4567',
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      './src/index'
    ],
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      publicPath: '/static/'
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
      loaders: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
        include: [`all of your dirs you want to watch`]
      }]
    }
  };
```

Comment: `include: [path.join(__dirname, 'src'), path.join(__dirname, 'src/app')]`
no reaction from WDS

Comment: you can try use exclude instead of include

Comment: `exclude: /node_modules/` without include option also does not work